# SSMS increase size of box Avaiable Databases

Tags: sql, ssms

In SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) there is a meny item Available Databases. I would like to increase the size of that box since there is some databases with long name that I would like to see the whole name.
Production name "VeryLongNameOfADatabaseInThisCase_Prod" "VeryLongNameOfADatabaseInThisCase_TEST".

Comment: Do you mean that you want to expand the right-hand panel which lists out databases on an instance? If so, you can move the panel slider to the right to resize the 'Object Explorer' panel. Alternatively, you can snap it out to have it on another window/screen. A screenshot of your issue would help.

Comment: No, mean up in the menu.

Comment: You're not making this easy Peter... Can you be more specific please, with some screenshots?

Comment: How do I add screen shots?
OPEN SSMS.
On the first meny row you have File, Edit, View, Query...

Comment: How do I add screen shots?
OPEN SSMS.
On the first meny row you have File, Edit, View, Query...

Comment: How do I add screen shots?
OPEN SSMS.
On the first meny row you have File, Edit, View, Query...
On the second menu row you have different buttons and "New Query"
ON the third you have Avaliable Databases, is it possible to make it bigger

Comment: OK, I have you. Answer is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Navigate to Tools > Customize
2. Go to the 'Commands' tab
3. Change the radio buttons on the left to 'Toolbar'
4. Select 'SQL Editor' from the list of options
5. Highlight 'Available Databases [__________]
6. Click 'Modify Selection'
7. Change the 'Width' property from 160 to a more meaningful value
8. Click Close

[image]

Hey presto, your Databases drop-down list is now wider.